# 20th century poem ending with "-baby?"

Tags: identification-request, poetry

In high school I rented a collection of poems from a male author that I believe had a black-and-white cover with a photograph on it. I got it from a USA library in 2012. I am looking for one poem in particular.

- it was a white American male poet. I would guess most active in the 1950s-60s but I'm not sure exactly
- the length of most of the poems was only ~15-30 lines. The book had ~100 pages' worth of poems
- the style of the poems was pretty simple, just some indentation and spacing but nothing too wild
- I remember this poem was vaguely romantic
- most specifically of all, I remember this poem ended with the author asking some question, with the last word of the poem being: "—baby?" (e.g. "what do you say—baby?" or something like this).

I've done searches of the most famous male poets of the era for poems ending with "baby?" to no avail. I've also looked through poem anthology book covers from the authors to see if any was familiar but nothing yet.